# How to change background color in kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have just started learning kivy. Please bear with me in case of my absurdity and stupidity.

Here just copy pasted the code from official [site](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html#quickstart).

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
      return Label(text='Hello world',)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And the output is  in the [link](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/_images/quickstart.png).

What I essentially wanted to know that how I can change the background (currently black) to some different color.

I have read some parts of documents ,Found documentation for changing color of widget but screen (probably not the accurate word).

I would really appreciate the advices and suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `canvas` of the `Label` to paint a background color like this:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyLabel(Label):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''
<MyLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
''')

class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
      return MyLabel(text='Hello world',)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

To do this without using the `kv` language is more complicated because you must set up the binding to `pos` and `size` that the `kv` language does for you automatically. Here is the equivalent without using `kv`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

    def on_pos(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.rect.size = self.size

        
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLabel(text='Hello world',)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

For more information about the `canvas`, see the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Canvas)

Comment: Thank you very much. How can we write purely in python without  any kv .Could you  could please give me more information for canvas.before

Comment: Dear  Sir, Thank you very much for the help.   After going through  the documentation  I have found another method using canvas.add . I have used it however, It looks it just on the top of my text. I just need to understand why it is so  and how canvas.before  was able to so.